# How to show items from last week?

Tags: php, laravel

How to show articles from **last week** ?

---

**PHP CODE**

```
$articles= Article::where('created_at', ">",   ?   )->take(100)->get();
```

---

> How to show articles from last week **from now** ?

Comment: Create i time 2017-7-29 12:00:00 where ? is, so date now minus 7 days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `whereBetween()` and Carbon to get data for previous week:

```
$start = Carbon::now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek();
$end = Carbon::now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek();
Article::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->take(100)->get();
```

Comment: Not using `DB::raw()`, love it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$articles= Article::where('created_at', ">=",  
DB::raw("curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY"))->take(100)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DB::raw()`

```
$articles= Article::where('created_at', ">", DB::raw('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK'))->take(100)->get();
```

I assume by `last week from now` means last 7 days from now

Answer (score -1):

I try this and it`s work for me !

```
$articles= Article::where('created_at', ">", date("Y-m-d HH:ii", time() - 10080 * 60))->take(100)->get();
```

Comment: i try this . . . is it true ?

Comment: USe Alexey Mezenin awnser

Comment: Not so readable;