# Query records from the last 7 days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]

**Today** is `2/24/2022`

On my report page, I read `interval` from the query params, and this is what I have in my controller:

```
$inputs    = Request::all();
$interval  = 'week'; // <<------------ Default Value 

if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
    $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
}


switch ($interval) {
    case 'day':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', now()->today());
    break;
    case 'week':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', now()->subWeek());
    break;
    case 'month':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', now()->subMonth());
    break;
    case 'year':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', now()->subYear());
    break;
    default:
    $q = BabyLog::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    break;
}




$logs = $q->where('babyId',$baby->id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get()->groupBy(function ($log) {
    return $log->updated_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

## dd($logs);

return

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#344 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    "2022-02-24" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#352 ▶}
    "2022-02-23" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#353 ▶}
    "2022-02-22" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#351 ▶}
    "2022-02-21" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#349 ▶}
    "2022-02-20" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#350 ▶}
    "2022-02-19" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#348 ▶}
    "2022-02-18" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#346 ▶}
    "2022-02-17" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#345 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I only want to display the last 7 days on my graph.

1. Why does `2022-02-17` is also on the list ??
2. What did I do wrong on the above codes?
3. Does subWeek() always return 8 ?
4. Should I just do subWeek() -1 ?

> *But ... subMonth(), and subYear() I don't have to do it.*

Comment: Do you have time expressions appended to these date values?  If so, then you are merely comparing `Y-m-d` versus `Y-m-d`, you are comparing `Y-m-d H:i:s` versions `Y-m-d` in which case `2022-02-17 00:00:01` will return `true` when compared against `2022-02-17`.  This would not be true if you were isolating pure `Y-m-d` `updated_at` values.  You have not shown us what `updated_at` contains. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-time-from-date-fields

Comment: I'm talking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55856968/2943403

Comment: use `whereDate` with date not datetime `now()` is datetime

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong about that, you dont have to do it in case of Month and year, it has same behavior. subWeek() substracts one whole week(same behavior for month and year), so if you substract a whole week from date 2022-02-24, you are getting final answer of 2022-02-17 (24-7=17)

**Solution**
changed '>' to '<'

```
case 'week':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '<', now()->subWeek());
break;
```

Other possible solution could be *whereBetween()*

```
$q->whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(),
    Carbon::now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek(),
]);
```

Also possible duplicate for question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387484/16833260

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You could try to use subDays(7) instead.

```
case 'week':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', now()->subDays(7));
break;
```

**Solution 2**

Using DB::raw.

```
case 'week':
    $q = BabyLog::where('updated_at', '>', DB::raw('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK'));
break;
```

Comment: That is the first thing, I tried. Same. show 8 results. :(

Comment: And subDays(6)? @code-8